# ¿Como utilizo div y mod separando el numero en billetes?

Tags: java

Necesito unas fórmulas en java que al momento de ingresar un número de "n" dígitos me los separe en billetes de 500 200 100 50 y 20 utilizando div y mod (estoy consciente que div es "/" y mod es "%").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilizaré un algoritmo simple para ayudarte a entender el problema.

Una manera de resolver esto es empezar a dividir el número entre los billetes de mayor denominación y con el residuo continuar dividiéndolo sucesivamente con los de menor denominación hasta que ya no quede nada.  Paso por paso:

Dígamos que el número inicial es `2790`

¿cuantos billetes de 500 podemos usar?

```
2790 div 500: 5
```

¿cuanto queda para repartir?

```
2790 mod 500: 290
```

y seguimos con el residuo

```
290 div 200: 1
290 mod 200: 90

90 div 100: 0
90 mod 100: 90

90 div 50: 1
90 mod 50: 40

40 div 20: 2
40 mod 20: 0
```

Entonces el resultado final es

- 5 de 500
- 1 de 200
- 0 de 100
- 1 de 50
- 2 de 20

Ahora intenta escribir el código con esta idea.

Answer (score 3):

Te paso una implementación usando el algoritmo indicado por @Equiso:

```
public class ContadorDeBilletes {

  private static int[] BILLETES;

  public static final int QUINIENTOS = 500;
  public static final int DOSCIENTOS = 200;
  public static final int CIEN = 100;
  public static final int CINCUENTA = 50;
  public static final int VEINTE = 20;
  public static final int DIEZ = 10;
  public static final int CINCO = 5;

  static {
    BILLETES = new int[] { QUINIENTOS, DOSCIENTOS, CIEN, CINCUENTA, VEINTE, DIEZ, CINCO };
  }

  public static Map<Integer, Integer> procesa(double importe) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> contador = init();
    if (importe <= 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Importe no valido....");
    }
    for (int index = 0; index < contador.size(); index++) {
      double resultado = importe / BILLETES[index];
      if (resultado > 0) {
        contador.put(BILLETES[index], (int) resultado);
      }
      importe = importe - ((int) resultado * BILLETES[index]);
    }
    return contador;
  }

  private static Map<Integer, Integer> init() {
    Map<Integer, Integer> contador = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    contador.put(QUINIENTOS, 0);
    contador.put(DOSCIENTOS, 0);
    contador.put(CIEN, 0);
    contador.put(CINCUENTA, 0);
    contador.put(VEINTE, 0);
    contador.put(DIEZ, 0);
    contador.put(CINCO, 0);
    return contador;
  }

}
```

Su tests:

```
public class ContadorDeBilletesTest {

  @Test
  public void test() {
    Map<Integer, Integer> contador = ContadorDeBilletes.procesa(5324.234);

    assertThat(contador.get(ContadorDeBilletes.QUINIENTOS), is(10));
    assertThat(contador.get(ContadorDeBilletes.DOSCIENTOS), is(1));
    assertThat(contador.get(ContadorDeBilletes.CIEN), is(1));
    assertThat(contador.get(ContadorDeBilletes.CINCUENTA), is(0));
    assertThat(contador.get(ContadorDeBilletes.VEINTE), is(1));
    assertThat(contador.get(ContadorDeBilletes.DIEZ), is(0));
    assertThat(contador.get(ContadorDeBilletes.CINCO), is(0));
  }

  @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
  public void testZero() {
    ContadorDeBilletes.procesa(0);
  }

  @Test
  public void testSinResto() {
    Map<Integer, Integer> contador = ContadorDeBilletes.procesa(500);

    assertThat(contador.get(ContadorDeBilletes.QUINIENTOS), is(1));
    assertThat(contador.get(ContadorDeBilletes.DOSCIENTOS), is(0));
    assertThat(contador.get(ContadorDeBilletes.CIEN), is(0));
    assertThat(contador.get(ContadorDeBilletes.CINCUENTA), is(0));
    assertThat(contador.get(ContadorDeBilletes.VEINTE), is(0));
    assertThat(contador.get(ContadorDeBilletes.DIEZ), is(0));
    assertThat(contador.get(ContadorDeBilletes.CINCO), is(0));
  }

}
```

Comment: Se agradece el test.

Comment: `if (importe <= 0) importe = importe*-1; boolean deboPasta = true;` XD

Comment: Intencionalmente omití la implementación ya que es obvio que el problema es una tarea/asignatura. Pero bueno...